# Scene has 1 camera but render has 2 objects.. one is faint

Tags: rendering

[image]

I imported this object from a .blend file so maybe there is already some kind of render object in the "renderlayers" object but I don't see a camera in there.. any idea what's happening here?

edit* here is the expanded UI. I couldn't see anything that looked duplicated (but I'm a noob)

[image]

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Is the image a render result? Can you show us the exploited version of your outliner? it could be that you have two copies of the mesh, one visible and renderable, the other not visible but renderable.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I updated with an image.

Comment: I also can't see anything strange. I think you should upload the file. So, the first image is a render result? Have you got something in the compositor?

Comment: Yeah.. I checked the compositor but nothing there. I ended up just copying the object layers to a new blender and it renders fine. There must be something about the script i'm running to render camera views that doesn't interact well with some setting in the original .blend file